# Xpath for a REST response with Keys

Tags: php, xml, rest, xpath, simplexml

I am trying to use Xpath to find a username value from a REST response. When I use

```
$data = new simpleXMLElement($response->getBody());
$matches = $data->xpath('//KEY[@name="username"]');
```

I get

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (2) {
["@attributes"]=>
array(1) {
["name"]=>
string(8) "username"
}
["VALUE"]=>
string(5) "guest"
}
}
```

My question is, what is the Xpath expression to get only the value to display? in this example it is guest, but will change depending on the user.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

XML structure below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<RESPONSE>
<MULTIPLE>
<SINGLE>
<KEY name="id">
<VALUE>1</VALUE> 
</KEY>
<KEY name="username">
<VALUE>guest</VALUE> 
</KEY>
<KEY name="firstname">
<VALUE>Guest user</VALUE> 
</KEY>
```

Comment: show us your xml please.

Comment: Hi Rob, Just added the XML up to where the user value is, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible with SimpleXML. The `xpath` method will always return an Array.

But you can do:

```
$keys = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo current($keys->xpath('//KEY[@name="username"]/VALUE'));
```

[demo](http://codepad.org/1DrrmJJz)

---

Or use DOM. The following will return the string immediately:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
echo $xpath->evaluate('string(//KEY[@name="username"]/VALUE)');
```

[demo](http://codepad.org/x75JOfPJ)

Comment: Hero! Definite mention in my dissertation for you! Much appreciated

Comment: Lol will do when it is released in July! I will make a note

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if simpleXml can evaluate this expression, but any compliant XPath implementation will:

```
string(//KEY[@name="username"]/VALUE)
```

When this expression is evaluated, the result is the string value of the `Value` element that is a child of the (first in document order) `KEY` element that has a `name` attribute, whose string value is `"username"`.

Also, if the structure of the XML document is known, then it may be more efficient (fast) not to use `//`:

```
string(/RESPONSE/MULTIPLE/SINGLE/KEY[@name="username"]/VALUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Dimitre, will definitely use the proper path as you suggested for efficiency purposes.